# Is K-כשר kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, rabbis, fish, dairy

What is the *kashrut* authority behind the K-כשר symbol that is now used on [Kirkland Signature milk sold at Costco](https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/Kirkland-Signature-2%25-Reduced-Fat-Milk%2C-1-Gallon.product.100082799.html)?:

[image: K-כשר symbol]

Comment: [Chicago Rabbinical Council](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) have an online list of common acceptable kosher symbols and their agencies' contact information. They say “The fact that a particular agency does not appear on this list does not imply that the cRc has determined it to be substandard.” The logo you show is not there. For $15, you can get their [2018 Supervsion Guide](https://hail.he.net/~kashrus/order_issue.php) that lists more than 1400 kosher certifying agencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my query to Costco they sent me the following information. K-כשר is Rabbi Aryeh Spero. He runs Quality Kosher Supervision and is located in Canton, OH. The milk comes from Superior Dairy Inc in Canton, OH.

Rabbi Spero also has another symbol - The Kaf-Q. I will try to see if I can add in the letter from Costco.

Comment: It's odd that he didn't use the Kaf-Q symbol and that he has no mention of the K-כשר symbol online(?)